# Just bought new monitor but has yellow tint

Tags: multiple-monitors

I just bought a new monitor and it's exactly the same model as the one I already was using. It's standing near my old monitor and compared to each other, the new monitor looks like it has a yellow-ish tint. It's a `Dell Ultrasharp U2412M`.

Can this be fixed, should I accept it the way it is or should I return the monitor (or would there be no chance for return because of such reason)?

Comment: How old is the previous monitor?  Quite often the lighting element (CCFL/LEDS) decays over time causing the display to look slightly dimmer or off-colour.  Generally professionals will buy pairs of monitors at the same time so that they "age" similarly.

Comment: Have you tried resetting its settings to the factory defaults? I would also recommend trying it with a different cable to see if the issue remains.

Comment: @PseudoSu As far as I could tell, both screens were at same settings. I don't know if this has anything to do with aging monitors and I could check on cables at least I guess. I'll add a comment or edit if I have more information.

Answer (score 1):

The monitor promotes itself, among other things thusly "Make colors cooler or warmer to suit your preference with the color temperature slider", and, from the specs "Customizable: Change your energy usage settings, text brightness and color temperature with the touch of a button to help conserve energy with this eco-designed arsenic-free and mercury-free panel." - I would thus posit that the monitor can simply be adjusted to have a cooler color.

It would seem unlikely to me that a new LED monitor would have a tint to it due to hardware issues - I've never seen a bright white LED with a yellow tint !

Comment: Exactly. I was just about to mention checking other Color Setting Modes as many times several of those put weird tinges of shading on everything (manual: https://fast.ulmart.ru/manuals/255724.pdf)

Comment: I tried tweaking with color settings but I can't get the exact same color as my old main monitor.